# How to find a vertex-induced subgraph with Eulerian cycle

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

How to find a vertex-induced subgraph with an Eulerian cycle?

The graph is connected and undirected.

Is the problem NP-Hard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get an Eulerian induced subgraph is to take the vertices of a shortest cycle. It's easy to see that this can be found in polynomial time, if it exists. (If no cycle exists, there is no nontrivial Eulerian induced subgraph, since every connected subgraph with at least one edge is a tree with at least two vertices of degree $1$.)